# Соединить каждую строку одного файла с каждой строкой другого

Tags: shell

Подскажите пожалуйста как объединить строки файлов, таким образом:

файл 1:

```
вася
петя
толя
```

файл 2:

```
иванов
петров
сидоров
```

Файл 3 (результат объединения):

```
вася иванов
вася петров
вася сидоров
петя иванов
петя петров
петя сидоров
толя иванов
толя петров
толя сидоров
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DOS shell (тест - Win10, CMD):

```
for /f %%a in (file1.txt) do (
    for /f %%b in (file2.txt) do (
        echo %%a %%b >> file3.txt
    )
)
```

*NIX shell (тест - Win10, Bash on Ubuntu on Windows):

```
while read word1; do while read word2; do echo "$word1 $word2" >> file3.txt; done < file2.txt; done < file1.txt
```

Comment: думаете, в вопросе всё-таки неправильная метка? (несмотря на явное указание в описании: «для вопросов о powershell используйте метку powershell») // ведь ваш ответ явно не будет работать в posix-совместимых оболочках.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin фиг знает... но вроде в *nix shell товарищ как-то разбирается, про `while read variable` знать должен...

Comment: Добавил *nix вариант.

Comment: Большое спасибо . Все работает как надо

Answer (score 0):

```
while read -r word1; do 
    (( line ++ ))
    word2="$(sed -n "${line}p" file2)"
    echo "$word1 $word2" >> file3
done < file1
```

Ну или в одну строчку если:

```
while read -r word1; do (( line ++ )); word2="$(sed -n "${line}p" file2)"; echo "$word1 $word2" >> file3; done < file1
```

Но если Вам нужен список каждого имени из file1 со всеми фамилиями из file2 то тогда вариант из первого ответа будет работать так как Вам необходимо.